# What format gpsd uses for feeding?

Tags: gps, gpsd

I need to replay collected gps data by gpsd for testing. I know that I can feed gpsd by tcp, for example: `gpsd -N tcp://127.0.0.1:6000`, but I can't find right format for feeding. What the format should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to replay the GPS data for testing, you can use `gpsfake` tool from the gpsd suite: https://gpsd.gitlab.io/gpsd/gpsfake.html

Regarding the log format that it can use

```
Logfiles for the use with gpsfake can be retrieved using gpspipe, gpscat, or cgps from the gpsd distribution, or any other application which is able to create a compatible output.
```

So I would record the log from a real GNSS receiver with

`gpspipe -R > gps.log`

and later use gpsfake to replay it during testing without GNSS receiver.

**edit:** The `gpspipe -R` command will save a NMEA log if the receiver outputs NMEA messages. It can be later used for testing with gpsfake or other tool. Of course you can kill gpsd and just directly listen to the serial port to record the NMEA.

Comment: Good idea, but not for my case. I used nmea messages for feading

Comment: This is exactly what I meant in the answer. If your receiver outputs NMEA, the `gpspipe -R > gps.log` will give you a file with NMEA messages.